# network connection status between server and other computers

Tags: c#, networking, server, status

i have requirement to check network status like up time and downtime.how many times connection between server and other computer got disconnected . what was the duration of disconnection. i want to know if there is any other way than ping in c# . as pinging is disabled by the administrator . i have already tried ping but its not working as i mentioned above its blocked. kindly suggest me some other way to get my work done.there are three computers which are connected to the server from where we are accessing those computer resources .it often disconnects due to poor connection so that is  why i need to implement this .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reliably be able to tell if the remote host is definitely unreachable, you should be using TCP. ICMP (ping) and UDP both don't guarantee delivery and simple packet loss could lead to false positives on connection loss.